# How to read ONLY the metadata bytes from a .net assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, metadata

Since Reflection only load no longer works in .NET Core, I'm implementing a wrapper around System.Reflection.Metadata to allow me to scan an assembly for the types it contains without a full assembly load.

Although the MetadataReader is basically working, I'm achieving it as follows:

```
 private unsafe MetadataReader LoadMetadataReader(
    string filename,
    MetadataReaderOptions options = MetadataReaderOptions.Default,
    MetadataStringDecoder decoder = null)
{
    buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
    pinnedHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    var headers = new PEHeaders(new MemoryStream(buffer));
    var startOffset = headers.MetadataStartOffset;
    var metaDataStart = (byte*)pinnedHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject() + startOffset;
    return new MetadataReader(metaDataStart, headers.MetadataSize, options, decoder);
}
```

This means I am loading ALL the bytes for the assembly each time.

My question is: **Is there a way of identifying and loading ONLY the subset of bytes from the file necessary to read the metadata?**

Comment: I don't have an answer, but a workaround (assuming the issue is memory usage) could be to create an AppDomain, load the type(s), and then unload it once you're done with reading the data.

Comment: Maybe you can feed `FileStream` instead of `MemoryStream` to `PEHeaders` constructor. Then it will (I assume) read only headers from that stream, and headers will provide you with information about size of metadata records, which you can then load.

Comment: I would try hard to use a MemoryMappedFile here.  Just like the CLR does.  A bit murky in .NETCore but there is a Nuget package for it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comment by Hans Passant, I worked it out:

Load the assembly as a [Memory Mapped File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files)

```
private static MemoryMappedFile LoadAssembly(string filename, out long length, out MemoryMappedFileAccess access)
{
    // Setup parameters to pass in
    return MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(filename, mode, mapName, length, access);
}
```

Create a [MemoryMappedViewStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedviewstream?view=netframework-4.7.1)

```
using (var file = LoadAssembly(filename, out var length, out var access)) {
    using (var stream = file.CreateViewStream(0, length, access)) {
```

Get the dimensions of the headers from the stream via a [PEHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.portableexecutable.peheaders?view=netcore-2.0) object

```
var headers = new PEHeaders(stream);
```

I was then able to get the actual pointer to the start of the file from the stream and pass it into the [MetadataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.metadata.metadatareader?view=netcore-2.0) constructor

```
var start = (byte*)0;
stream.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.AcquirePointer(ref start);
var size = headers.MetadataSize;
var reader = new MetadataReader(start + headers.MetadataStartOffset, size, options, decoder);
```